# Python not opening Japanese filenames

Tags: python, windows, unicode, file-io

I've been working on a python script to open up a file with a unicode name (Japanese mostly) and save to a randomly generated (Non-unicode) filename in Windows Vista 64-bit, and I'm having issues... It just doesn't work, it works fine with non-unicode filenames (Even if it has unicode content), but the second you try to pass a unicode filename in - it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
try:
    import sys, os
    inpath = sys.argv[1]
    outpath = sys.argv[2]
    filein = open(inpath, "rb")
    contents = filein.read()
    fileSave = open(outpath, "wb")
    fileSave.write(contents)
    fileSave.close()

    testfile = open(outpath + '.test', 'wb')
    testfile.write(inpath)
    testfile.close()

except:
    errlog = open('G:\\log.txt', 'w')
    errlog.write(str(sys.exc_info()))
    errlog.close()
```

And the error:

```
(<type 'exceptions.IOError'>, IOError(2, 'No such file or directory'), <traceback object at 0x01092A30>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert your `inpath` to unicode, like this:

```
inpath = sys.argv[1]
inpath = inpath.decode("UTF-8")
filein = open(inpath, "rb")
```

I'm guessing you are using Python 2.6, because in Python 3, all strings are unicode by default, so this problem wouldn't happen.

Comment: @Daniel, that's right, it's probably encoded in something else, such as shift_jis, euc-jp, or iso-2022-jp perhaps.

Comment: Can you post the entire exception, instead of using `sys.exc_info()`, you can do `except IOError, e:` and then write `str(e)` into the error log file.

Comment: No such file or directory: u'G:\\misc\\2010-06-22 \u690d\u8349\u3042\u304b\u306d.txt'

Comment: What is the actual file's name in Japanese?

Comment: Actually, there was a bit of a blunder on my part... I fixed it and it turns out inpath.decode("UTF-8") worked Thanks :)

Comment: No problem.  UTF-8 is so common these days because it is basically extended ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that sys.argv[1](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572200/) and sys.argv[2] are just byte arrays and don't support natively Unicode.  You could confirm this by printing them and seeing if they are the character you expect.  You should also print type(sys.argv[1](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572200/)) to make sure they are of the correct type.

Where do the command-line parameters come from?  Do they come from another program or are you typing them on the command-line?  If they come from another program, you could have the other program encode them to UTF-8 and then have your Python program decode them from UTF-8.

Which version of Python are you using?

Edit: here's a robust solution: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572200/

Comment: Actually I did something similar - I took out the first open, and replaced content with both the args that are passed in - and they're passed in fine, the file is saved with the exact filenames that I set, even if the first one is unicode.
And it's coming from PHP, but that's not an issue - I've also tried by hard-coding the filenames.

Comment: @Jon: It saves the exact filenames that you set... but in what encoding?  You should also save str(type(sys.argv[1])) to see if Python thinks that sys.argv is a str or unicode type.

Comment: I'm not sure, what's the best way to check? Also, I put str(type(sys.argv[1])) into the error log and it spits out: <type 'str'>

Comment: It's definitely a str type, in Python 2 its always a str type unless if you convert it to unicode.

Comment: @jcao219 this all seems like a massive pita... What do I need to do to get this working in 3? When I tried to use Python 3.0.1's python.exe to run the script, it spits out some error messages.

Comment: Take out the unicode() function, it does not exist in Python 3 because all strings are unicode.

Also change `except IOError, e:` to `except IOError as e:`

Comment: @Jon: I edited my answer with a link to a solution that should work (in Python 2)

Comment: @Daniel: Wow! that's a cool solution with ctypes.  It would make this program windows-specific, but that is okay I think for the OP's purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the other answer turned out to be what I needed but I'm definitely saving that link in case I need it later.

Comment: @jcao219: True, but only Windows uses Unicode natively for filenames anyway.  On Unixy systems you can just pass bytes around.