# How to read japanese filename file correctly by python in windows

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

```
import os

path="."
dirList=os.listdir(path)

for fileName in dirList:
    print fileName
```

if the filename is **japanese**, print to console will be not correct(like ?????.csv,????abc.csv)

```
open('XXX.csv').readlines()
```

if the filename is **japanese**,
IOError:No such file or directory: \xe4\xb8\xbcABC.csv

Comment: what about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089700/python-not-opening-japanese-filenames

Comment: The python2 libraries are terrible when it comes to unicode support, some libs have backward compatible "workarounds" but some other libs (like subprocess) don't.

Comment: fileName = fileName.decode("UTF-8")(from jmunsch's link) still IOError, change file name to english is OK

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052225/convert-python-filenames-to-unicode

Comment: fileName2 = fileName.decode("UTF-8")  open('fileName2').readlines()  it works.But fileName must Japanese string, I can not get the correct fileName(become ???.csv) by os.listdir(),must hard code fileName.This question can be summarized to "how to get correct japanese fileName by os.listdir()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All problems done,thanks

1)if you want to get fileNames which is not English(such as Japanese,Chinese) by os.listdir correctly(not ???.csv)
you can add u before your path string
[listdir doesn't print non-english letters correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954948/listdir-doesnt-print-non-english-letters-correctly)

2)if you want to open a file,you can use file.decode('UTF-8')

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

dirList=os.listdir(u"C:\\")

for file in dirList:
    print file
    file2 = file.decode('UTF-8')
    count = len(open('C:\\' + file2).readlines())
    print count
```